# Retain the view on fragment tab change

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-view, android-fragmentactivity

I have a tabbed application, say 2 tabs. It was initially developed using ActivityGroup. However, having realized that multi-panes are not supported in ActivityGroup, I decided to use fragments. Before going to the problem, let me brief you about the application.

So, like I said before it is a tabbed application

```
TabA---> Activity1---> Activity2---> Activity3

TabB---> Activity4---> Activity5----> Activity6
```

This is the work pattern of my old activity-group based app.

Now with fragments, this would change into something like below

```
FragmentActivity---> TabAFragment---> FragmentA1---> FragmentA2
               |
                ---> TabBFragment---> FragmentB1---> FragmentB2
```

Each fragment connects to server for data on initial load.

And in the transaction, I replace fragment every time I add.

```
FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.realtabcontent, fragment);
ft.commit();
```

**What is observed**

I have only one activity(FragmentActivity-where tabs are created) for those two tab fragments. I share this activity for all tabs. For instance, I load fragmentB1 in tabB- inflates a view, fetches data from server and displays in a ListView. Then I switch to other tabA and loads fragmentA1. So far so good. Now if I go back to tabB, I want to see the listView which was loaded earlier. What happens is it starts everything from square one.

This is my first-hand experience with fragments. I did a bit of research; however it didn't really help fix mine.

How can I retain already loaded view?

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Hi I'm fairly new to all the fragments also. However, I was doing something similar and found that I needed to add the current fragment to the back stack like so.

```
ft.addToBackStack (null);
```

This line would go just before your comit so your code becomes:

```
FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.realtabcontent, fragment);
ft.addToBackStack (null);
ft.commit();
```

Hopefully this is of some use.